# Web Service roda mas ao consumir método dá erro

Tags: web-service, rest, wcf, iis, aplicação-web

Lutei para configurar meu web service no IIS. Ele sobe, mostrando a tela de que o WS está ok. Acontece que quando eu passo um parâmetro para ele dá esse erro:

```
REQUEST ERROR
The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.
```

O IIS está num servidor AMAZON(Cloud).

Meu método

```
public TPDV getCnpjParceiro(string cnpj)
        {
            V99_WEBEntities db = new V99_WEBEntities();
            TPDV pdv = new TPDV();
            List<string> lista = new List<string>();

            var resultado = (from _lista in db.T_PDV
                             where _lista.CNPJ == cnpj
                             join _st in db.T_CRM_StatusPDV on _lista.CNPJ equals(_st.DE_Cnpj)
                             join _sc in db.T_Script on _st.IT_Status equals((int)_sc.TipoStatus)
                             select new
                             {
                                 _lista.CNPJ,
                                 _lista.RazaoSocial,
                                 _lista.Endereco,
                                 _lista.CaminhoLogo,
                                 _lista.Bairro,
                                 _lista.Cidade,
                                 _st.IT_Status,
                                 _st.DT_TransacaoV,
                                 tecnico = _sc.TipoScript == "T" ? _sc.Script : null,
                                 central = _sc.TipoScript == "C" ? _sc.Script : null
                             }).ToList();

            foreach (var lis in resultado)
            {
                pdv.CNPJ = lis.CNPJ;
                pdv.RazaoSocial = lis.RazaoSocial;
                pdv.Endereco = lis.Endereco;
                pdv.CaminhoLogo = lis.CaminhoLogo;
                pdv.Bairro = lis.Bairro;
                pdv.Cidade = lis.Cidade;
                pdv.ScriptCentral = lis.central;
                pdv.ScriptTecnico = lis.tecnico;
            }

            return pdv;

        }
```

Passo o parâmetro assim:

```
meu_ip/WebServiceSuporteTecnico/SuporteTecnicoServiceWS.svc/pesquisa/um_cnpj_da_minha_base
```

Comment: Código do método que você está tentando chamar e os parâmetros passados na chamada, por favor

Comment: ok, editando a pergunta

Comment: Comigo na minha máquina, funciona bem. Somente no cloud(IIS) é que está dando pau

Comment: Esse serviço é `REST`? Você configurou o parâmetro default `CNPJ` nas configurações? Só para testar, mude `string cnpj` para `string id`. Se funcionar é problema de configuração

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolvi. O erro era o seguinte: Quando eu subi os arquivos para o IIS que está em uma máquina remota na Amazon, eu enviei também o meu web.config. O banco de dados que eu estou usando, se encontra na mesma máquina. Conversando com o cara que administra o Amazon aqui na empresa, ele me disse que o IP não é um IP real, é um IP mascarado, que aponta para o IP real, para que o mundo externo não tenha conhecimento do IP real. Como ele estava tentando acessar o banco por esse IP, ele não conseguia sair, pois é só um IP fictício e dava esse pau. Quando abri o Event Viewer do servidor e vi o erro de underlying open() do banco de dados, aí pude saber que era um problema com a conexão e era isso que estava dando o erro. Bem, peguei o IP do web.config e alterei tudo para localhost, pois o banco e o iis estão no mesmo ambiente físico, logo o BD está em localhost. Fiz isso e agora está funcionando.